# Heap Algorithm. Really basic, about array position 0 and 1.

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist, heap

Heap - Sort Algorithm
The problem I am having is this, this algorithms n input is 2, this is designed so that the 1st position (int i) of the array and the 2nd position (int j) have their values compared.

The problem is that this ignores the 0 position of the given array list. I have tried reducing certain values, this will create infinite loops. The algorithm is an adaptation of pseudocode. It isn't designed to run arraylist from 0. I can't think of how to re-adapt this algorithm into a decent minimum heap sort.

```
public static void input( ArrayList<input> vertexList, int n )
{
    int j=n; 
    int i=n/2; 
    input object = vertexList.get(n);

    while ((i>0) && vertexList.get(i)> object){

        vertexList.set(j, vertexList.get(i));

        j = i;
        i = i/2;
    }

    vertexList.set(j, object);

}
```

Comment: The parent index in a 0-indexed array is `(i-1)/2`, not `i/2`

Comment: @harold I tried that, the problem is that whatever data is inputted, the heap will start the comparison from position [1] > [2], and not [0] > [1]

Comment: What about i>=0 instead of i>0 in your while loop?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut The problem then would be if j=1 i=0 then the loop would be infinite

Comment: @HopelessProgrammer Print i and j in every iteration before and after their recomputation. That should give a clue.

Comment: @ElKamina I printed the statements and found that the first element of the arraylist is out right ignored, whilst the remaining elements are sorted to a heap format.

Comment: @HopelessProgrammer I think the problem lies with second part of the while statement: "vertexList.get(i)> object". When you do vertexList.get(n) it probably returns 0 (since probably your array has only n elements indexed from 0 to n-1). If the first element of the array is 0, then the second part of while is never executed for i=0. To sum it all, check if vertexList.get(0)>vertexList.get(n) is ever True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `vertexList.get(i-1)` and `vertexList.get(j-1)` and `vertexList.set(j-1, ...)`

Comment: This has helped solve the problem however the array is now not sorting the final arrayList location.

Comment: Maybe you should show the entire code you are using to test this.